# Has any research lab done serious work to engineer new bacteria which assemble graphene wafers?

Tags: recombinant, protein-engineering

I was thinking about crazy uses for engineered bacteria. Nano-assembly of Graphene seems like a potentially excellent target for the technology. Have any research/full-blown labs worked on this? Any papers on it?
What would be some of the difficulties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly, the answer is yes. In 2012 Tanizawa et al published a paper titled [Microorganism mediated synthesis of reduced graphene oxide films](http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-6596/352/1/012011). The gist of it is that most of the steps (including the structuring of the graphene sheet) were carried out with chemical synthesis, but a final reduction step from graphene oxide to graphene was carried out using bacteria from a local river.

Probably not quite what you were thinking of, but I imagine this is the closest you'll get for right now.

Comment: cool... as I am interested in nanotech, this is very impressive...+1